# PHP or MYSQL : how to group results by ROW?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm working on mysql
those are my tables

```
D
----------
id , name
----------
1  , d1
2  , d2
3  , d3

t
----------
id , name
----------
1  , t1
2  , t2
3  , t3

c
----------
id , d_id , t_id
----------
1  , 1    , 1
1  , 1    , 2
1  , 1    , 3
1  , 2    , 1
1  , 2    , 2
1  , 2    , 3
1  , 3    , 1
1  , 3    , 2
1  , 3    , 3
```

i want to produce a query to get result like this

```
-------------------------------------------
d.name , t.name , t.name , t.name
-------------------------------------------
d1     , t1     , t2     , t3
d2     , t1     , t2     , t3
d3     , t1     , t2     , t3
```

is that possible ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

*if it's not possible, is there any idea on how to get it as an array or object using PHP ?*

Comment: Are there going to be the same number of t.names for each d.name?

Comment: The context and meaning of d, t and c might be able to shed more light on what you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: @My other me, d for day and t for time, a day time table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, dynamically generating columns in MySQL is not a good idea. You'd be better of just selecting the d.name - t.name pairs, and then creating a hash per d.name.

For example, Perl has a [fetchall_hashref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573370/perl-dbi-fetchall-hashref) that could suit you. Other languages often have the same functionality built-in, but you didn't specify a programming language other than pure SQL.

Comment: that looks exactly as i want, do you have any idea how to do this in PHP ?

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert, but most people here on StackOverflow like PDO. [It seems to appear PDO supports this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), but that might warrant another question (or an edit here). Offcourse there are always [workarounds](http://snipplr.com/view/1358/mysql-fetch-all/).